# Padrino - Sass, Coffee - Encoding::UndefinedConversionError, from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

Tags: encoding, coffeescript, padrino

How to reproduce

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'haml'
gem 'sass'
gem 'coffee-script'
```

**app/app.rb**

```
get '/javascripts/rus_test.js' do
  content_type 'text/javascript', charset: 'utf-8'
  coffee :"../../public/javascripts/rus_test"
end
```

**public/javascripts/rus_test.coffee (it's work)**

```
alert 'Hello World!'
```

**localhost:3000/javascripts/rus_test.js**

```
(function() {

  alert('Hello World!');

}).call(this);
```

**public/javascripts/rus_test.coffee (doesn't work)**

```
alert 'Привет!'
```

**GIVES ERROR**

Encoding::UndefinedConversionError at /javascripts/rus_test.js
"\xD0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

I tried to set several variants of Encoding.default in **config/boot.rb**.

**one of variants of boot initializing**

```
Padrino.before_load do
  Encoding.default_internal = nil
  # Encoding.default_external = 'ASCII-8BIT'
end
```

It's work for HAML with russian text, but **doesn't work for SASS and COFFEE**

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: I'm using Sinatra (which Padrino is based on) + [Sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets) to serve the assets and can process `alert 'Привет!'` with no problem. Is the file correctly encoded as UTF-8? Can you compile it with the `coffee` command?

Comment: we are complilled with pure coffee. Works fine! Code in Sinatra works fine. Probably Padrino needs for some Magick comment some where?

Comment: Iam use Sublime Text Editor with utf-8.

Answer (score 2):

Remove ridiculous `Encoding.default_internal = nil` and add this code somewhere to monkey patch Tilt:

```
# this makes tilt to treat templates as properly encoded (respect Encoding.default_external)
module Tilt
  class CoffeeScriptTemplate
    def prepare
      @data.force_encoding Encoding.default_external
      if !options.key?(:bare) and !options.key?(:no_wrap)
        options[:bare] = self.class.default_bare
      end
    end
  end
end
```